# (Python) Is numpy.polynomial.polynomial broken in numpy 1.13.1 version?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Trying to import numpy and call np.polynomial.polynomial

```
import gym
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
print(np.__version__)
methods =[method_name for method_name in dir(np.polynomial)
 if callable((getattr(np.polynomial, method_name)))]
print(methods)
polyvalfromroots = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyvalfromroots
from policy_gradient import util
from policy_gradient.policy import CategoricalPolicy
```

result:

```
1.13.1
['Chebyshev', 'Hermite', 'HermiteE', 'Laguerre', 'Legendre', 'Polynomial', '_numpy_tester', 'bench', 'test']

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-41682dd8722b> in <module>()
      6  if callable((getattr(np.polynomial, method_name)))]
      7 print(methods)
----> 8 polyvalfromroots = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyvalfromroots
      9 from policy_gradient import util
     10 from policy_gradient.policy import CategoricalPolicy

AttributeError: module 'numpy.polynomial' has no attribute 'polynomial'
```

It has been modified to np.polynomial.Polynomial.

But the document [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyvalfromroots.html) still write numpy.polynomial.polynomial

Is that a bug? What version of numpy should I restore to use numpy.polynomial.polynomial ?

Comment: cannot reproduce.

Comment: Am I the only one having this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why I got that bug.
But it was solved by reinstall my numpy

```
conda remove numpy
conda install numpy=1.13
```